# Blackberry error: "Module attempts to access secure API"

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to run my application on Blackberry 9360. I am getting an error:

> `Module attempts to access secure API`

I have already signed the application, but still I am getting this error. Can anybody tell me the solution?

Comment: try to change all application permissions then try

Comment: possible duplicate of [Module attempts to access secure API: RIM Blackberry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545905/module-attempts-to-access-secure-api-rim-blackberry)

Answer (score 2):

1. You will need to sign the code every time you make a new build.
2. I had to move the code over to blackberry device using Eclipse >  > Load Project(s) on device, as opposed to using blackberry desktop manager.
3. If you are using Windows, make sure you have turned UAC off.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your signing keys are valid. If it is please build the code again and re-sign it. So the sign the code again and make sure all succeeds. it should work. I had a look at [Signing server status](http://isthesigningserverdown.com) and it shows that some of them failed. So maybe you tried to sign during the failure period.